# Acer Aspire One and Kernel 2.6.35-25 Freeze

Tags: acer, aspire-one, external-monitor

I'm having a problem with an Acer Aspire One netbook after the latest kernel upgrade. Basically, doing anything relating to an external monitor locks the trackpad, and in some cases, the keyboard as well. This lock will continue in Gnome even after reboots, and requires battery removal to fix. It does work in the graphical login manager up until the problem occurs the first time. And ideas on settings, etc, that I can change to make it work again?

Comment: Seems to be working after the (unrelated) SSL/Kerberos updates ... I'm wondering if the fix was actually because of reconfigured XOrg configuration. I did try a dpkg-reconfigure on xorg earlier when it wasn't working and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: The reconfigured xorg above I'm assuming would have occurred when I had the dual monitor setup working again under the old kernel ... the same setup then worked successfully for the new one ... just guessing here.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

use 2.6.35-24
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/703553

Comment: This may be related, but the behavior described is quite different (although it does vary across hardware).